# Table width not working, shifted too far left

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have made this newsletter, but for some reason the header is shifted to the right. 
I have no idea what could be causing this. O.o
http://jsfiddle.net/3hVFp/

When I do just the top:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="810px" style="border:1px solid white;border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
            <td VALIGN=TOP style="width:25%; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">Nieuwsbrief #6</td>
            <td style="width:50%; background: #DBDBDB;"><img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="http://pietrow.net/newsletter/images/lad_wide.png"></img></td>
            <td align="right" style="width:25%; vertical-align: top; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;" >Datum: 13-10-13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #DBDBDB; border: 1px solid #000000; border-top: 0px; border-left: 1px solid #000000;">
            <td ><center><a href="http://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~kaiser/">Website</a></center></td>
            <td ><center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LADKaiser">Facebook</a></center></td>
            <td ><center><a href="mailto:kaiser@strw.leidenuniv.nl">Contact</a></center></td>
    </tr>
```

It works though.
http://jsfiddle.net/3hVFp/2/

Does anybody have a clue as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width attributes with percentages from td elements and replace with colspan
1st part

```
<tr style="background: #DBDBDB; border: 1px solid #000000; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;">
            <td colspan="1"><center><a href="http://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~kaiser/">Website</a></center>

            </td>
            <td colspan="1"><center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LADKaiser">Facebook</a></center></td>
            <td colspan="1"><center><a href="mailto:kaiser@strw.leidenuniv.nl">Contact</a></center>


            </td>
            </tr>
```

2nd part

```
<tr style="background: #DBDBDB; border: 1px solid #000000;" width="810px">
            <td>

                <b>Board L.A.D. 'F. Kaiser'</b><br>
                <center><br>
                Alex Pietrow<br>
                Josha van Houdt<br>
                Emanuele Di Gloria<br>
                Pawel Biernacki<br>
                Guus de Wit<br>
                Queeny van der Spek<br>
                </center>
            </td>

                <td colspan="2"><center>

                L.A.D. 'F. Kaiser'<br>
                Niels Bohrweg 2<br>
                2333 CA Leiden<br>
                <a href="mailto:kaiser@strw.leidenuniv.nl">kaiser@strw.leidenuniv.nl</a>
                </center>



            </td>

            </tr>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ It still does not quite work.
But I think this is a step in the right direcion. (litteraly :P)

Comment: I think it works  have a closer look http://jsfiddle.net/3hVFp/4/show/  , at least it looks the same as http://jsfiddle.net/3hVFp/2/show/ .

Comment: I've updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u9pjc/1/ , now it is ok. You hadn't replaced the percentages with colspan   the part (...<td width="33%"><center><a href="http://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~kaiser/">Website</a>...)

Answer (score 0):

Your last `<tr>` looks like this:

```
<tr style="background: #DBDBDB; border: 1px solid #000000;" width="810px">
    <td width="50%">
      ..
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      ..
    </td>
</tr>
```

instead of

```
<tr ..>
  <td colspan="3">
    another <table> since you want different layout
  </td>
</tr>
```

That is shifting it to the right.

P.S.: Hint for debugging: Delete contents element by element, to see what's causing the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue

please check the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3hVFp/3/

i have removed `<td="width=50%">`

Answer (score -1):

You really shouldn't style using tables, that's what CSS is for

Comment: It's a newsletter, it only gets oldschool html